# Make selection on duplicate result sets

Tags: sql, sap-ase

I've searched for days around the net, read books and all of that, but I can't get it done. That's why I signed up with stackoverflow, I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance for your time and effort!

Given is the next table:

```
 column1    column2    column3
 ---------- ---------- ----------
 A          X          1
 A          X          3
 A          Y          1
 A          Y          2
 A          Z          1
 A          Z          2
```

```
select * from t where column2 = Y
```

and

```
select * from t where column2 = Z
```

have the same result set; 1 , 2

```
select * from t where column2 = X
```

has a different result set; 1 , 3

How can I select values in column2 that have duplicate result sets, if combined with column3?

I would like to have a selection query that gives me Y and Z, because they both have 1+2 as a result, and not X, because X has 1+3.

Comment: Do you have a _table_ with the name `column3`? Very odd name...

Comment: please explain better with input data, current sql, current output and expected output

Comment: You can do this with grouping over column2 and a string aggregation on column2 having Count > 1.

Comment: How big does that column3 integer get? and is it distinct for each column2 value, or could the same column3 value exist multiple times for a single column2?

Comment: @jarih Maybe my post wasn't clear, but column1, column2 and column3 are three columns of the same table.

Comment: @Christian4143 There is no such thing as string aggergation (list or concat) in Sybase, I already looked into that, otherwise that would be a great solution.

Comment: @JNevill The integer can be anything and can exist more then once in relation to column2, that's gonna be a problem.

Comment: @jarih I see now I wrote 'from column' that's really confusing, I'm sorry, I was too buys making the post nice and didn't look at the syntax anymore.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with set-based operations.  A bit of a pain, but:

```
select a.col2, b.col2
from t a join
     t b
     on a.col1 = b.col1 and  -- assume this is needed
        a.col3 = b.col3 and
        a.col2 < b.col2
group by a.col2, b.col2
having count(*) = (select count(*) from t where t.col1 = a.col1 and t.col2 = a.col2) and
       count(*) = (select count(*) from t where t.col1 = b.col1 and t.col2 = b.col2) ;
```

This is slightly easier to express using window functions, but not all versions of Sybase support those.